# Makefile that passes its command-line parameters to another script

Tags: makefile, command-line-arguments

In a project, I have a script called make.sh that builds the project and does some other stuff too. It is working well so far.

Then, just out of curiosity I've tried to create a Makefile that just passed its command-line parameters to this script so I could call it 
    make snapshot
instead of
    ./make.sh snapshot

this is the Makefile that I'm using right now

```
.PHONY: snapshot

%: 
    ./make.sh $@

snapshot: 
    ./make.sh snapshot
```

But this approach have some problems, I can't pass "build" as a parameter, because I have a "Build" directory (used by SCons), and I can't pass a second parameter to be passed to the script, like:
    make upload 192.168.1.10
as `make` interprets it as two different targets...

Is there a way I can do this with the Makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it:

```
%:all
    @true

all:
    ./make.sh $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

but this is an abuse of Make. The idea is that Make should interpret its arguments as a set of targets, not an ordered list of general arguments. You should probably use a different tool.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. And yes, I know its an abuse of Make, but this is more for the sake of curiosity than anything else. Thanks!